# Wordpress unknown database error with select

Tags: php, database, wordpress

This is code from child functions.php:

```
function f_goscie(){
    global $wpdb;
    $kateg = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM kategorie');
}

add_shortcode('goscie','f_goscie');
```

And this is code from my plugin:

```
function dominik_play(){
    global $wpdb;
    define( 'DIEONDBERROR', true ); //i have multisite on
    $wpdb->show_errors();

    $kateg = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM kategorie');
    $wpdb->print_error();
}

add_shortcode('ytplejer','dominik_play');
```

The first code works without any problems. It's part of bigger code which gets data from my own tables
http://niezaleznylublin.pl/nasi-goscie/

The second code throws this error:

> Wordpress database error: [] SELECT * FROM kategorie

niezaleznylublin.pl/player

I dont have ANY ideas why those two very similar functions give different results and one is error.

Comment: Do you have some php errormessages? Please take a look into your PHP errorlog file.

Comment: After translation : `Database error while doing query SELECT * FROM kategorie sent by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/hueman/page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), call_user_func_array, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, call_user_func, fdominik_play`. I dont think wp-blog-header.php and template-loader.php are problems so i checked templates page.php file but havent found anything suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing arround with solutions i found with "wpdb plugin" phrase. I tried normal mysqli queries. They didnt work either. Then i tried them on child functions.php and i dont know why but they started to work. I came back to plugin and rolled back changes and sudently all begun to work. Im happy that i can move forward but the same way im frustrated that i couldnt find any reasonable explanation what was the problem